# Why do gifs sent to Twitter using UIActivityViewController end up as jpg?

Tags: ios, twitter, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to send a gif to twitter using  this code:

```
NSURL *imagePath = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"example" ofType:@"gif"]];
NSData *gifItem = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imagePath];
NSArray *sharingItems = @[gifItem, @"TEST"];
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:sharingItems applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

However the gif ends up as a single frame jpg on Twitter feed.
I've tried several gifs, some of them end up fine, some end up as a single frame. There's not much difference between them, maybe size, but it's still below 5MB limit Twitter has.

I've tried to upload the gif to Giphy first and display it in feed, like in case of facebook, but then the gif is not displayed in line.

I've checked some other apps on ios which do the same I want to, and they share quite long gifs [up to 5 seconds, large in resolution] and it works for them fine. Don't know why mine end up as a single frame jpg.

Thanks
Krystian

EDIT:
after making the gif below 200KB, the file became playable inline on twitter. But I am certain that the other gifs that are playable inline on twitter are far bigger.

Comment: I have the same problem. This seems to be a limitation with Twitter itself. A [post in the Twitter Dev forums](https://twittercommunity.com/t/sharing-animated-gif-image-to-twitter-via-uiactivityviewcontroller/95740) about the same problem never been answered as well.